# I am getting an error when running new app in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm-install

I have already installed LTS version of Node.But not able to run my first app. 
I just followed this link "https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/" for installation process.

Already verified `npm version` and `node version`... everything is fine right now.

Error Log:

```
Prakashs-MacBook-Pro-4:~ prakash$ sudo ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial
Password:
✔ Creating directory ./MyIonicProject - done!
✔ Downloading and extracting tutorial starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and
 Android? Yes
✔ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
✔ Downloading integration cordova - done!
✔ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Added cordova integration!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ✨   IONIC  DEVAPP  ✨

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  -     Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  -     LiveReload for instant style and JS updates



> npm i
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):



        > fsevents@1.1.3 install 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/fsevents
        > node install

        [fsevents] Success: 
        "/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" 
        already installed
        Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

        > node-sass@4.7.2 install 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
        > node scripts/install.js

        Unable to save binary 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 
        : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
        '/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
             at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
             at sync 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
             at Function.sync 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
             at checkAndDownloadBinary 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
             at Object.<anonymous> 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
             at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
             at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
             at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
             at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
             at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
           errno: -13,
           code: 'EACCES',
           syscall: 'mkdir',
           path: '/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
        > node lib/post_install.js


        > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
        > node scripts/build.js

        Building: /usr/local/bin/node 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js 
        rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= 
        --libsass_library=
        gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
        gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
        gyp verb cli   
        '/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
        gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
        gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
        gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
        gyp info using node@8.11.1 | darwin | x64
        gyp verb command rebuild []
        gyp verb command clean []
        gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
        gyp verb command configure []
        gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the 
        PATH
        gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at 
        getNotFoundError 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    
        at F (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n 
           at E 
        (/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    
        at /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    
        at /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    
        at /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at 
        FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
        gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
        gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the 
        PATH
        gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
        gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; 
        print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
        gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to 
        host node version: 8.11.1
        gyp verb command install [ '8.11.1' ]
        gyp verb install input version string "8.11.1"
        gyp verb install installing version: 8.11.1
        gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already 
        installed
        gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check 
        "installVersion"
        gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
        gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
        gyp verb install version is good
        gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.11.1
        gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build
        gyp ERR! configure error 
        gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
        '/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build'
        gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
        gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
        "/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
        "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" 
        "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
        gyp ERR! cwd /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
        gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
        gyp ERR! not ok 
        Build failed with error code: 1
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR! 
        npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
        additional logging output above.

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     
        /Users/prakash/.npm/_logs/2018-04-02T13_38_21_394Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Your issue is right in the stack trace: `Unable to save binary 
        /Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 
        : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
        '/Users/prakash/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'`. You need to check your filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 0):

it fails because of permission error, try

```
sudo npm i
```